# threedubmedia - jquery.event.drop - registering an element as a drop target

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been examining the examples and http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/dragover does what I need to achieve - the draggable knows over what droppable it is.

However, I do not know how to add my own element (e.g. div) and make it a drop target. In the sample, all I see is that the drop method is used. Is this equivalent to registering an element as a drop target?

Sorry if my question seems dumb, I've done all my programming on server-side and I'm just starting to use JS.

Cheers,
Maciej.